# Understanding CUDA serialization and reconvergence point

Tags: serialization, cuda

**EDIT:** I realized that I, unfortunately, overlooked a semicolon at the end of the `while` statement in the first example code and misinterpreted it myself. So there is in fact an empty loop for threads with `threadIdx.x != s`, a convergency point after that loop and a thread waiting at this point for all the others without incrementing the `s` variable. I am leaving the original (uncorrected) question below for anyone interested in it. Be aware, that there is a semicolon missing at the end of the second line in the first example and thus, `s++` has nothing in common with the cycle body.

--

We were studying serialization in our CUDA lesson and our teacher told us that a code like this:

```
__shared__ int s = 0;
while (s != threadIdx.x)
    s++; // serialized code
```

would end up with a HW deadlock because the nvcc compiler puts a *reconvergence point* between the `while (s != threadIdx.x)` and `s++` statements. If I understand it correctly, this means that once the reconvergence point is reached by a thread, this thread stops execution and waits for the other threads until they reach the point too. In this example, however, this never happens, because thread #0 enters the body of the while loop, reaches the reconvergence point without incrementing the `s` variable and other threads get stuck in an endless loop.

A working solution should be the following:

```
__shared__ int s = 0;
while (s < blockDim.x)
    if (threadIdx.x == s)
        s++; // serialized code
```

Here, all threads within a block enter the body of the loop, all evaluate the condition and only thread #0 increments the `s` variable in the first iteration (and loop goes on).

My question is, why does the second example work if the first hangs? To be more specific, the `if` statement is just another point of divergence and in terms of the Assembler language should be compiled into the same conditional jump instruction as the condition in the loop. So why isn't there any reconvergence point before `s++` in the second example and has it in fact gone immediately after the statement?

In other sources I have only found that a divergent code is computed independently for every branch - e.g. in an `if/else` statement, first the `if` branch is computed with all `else`-branched threads masked within the same warp and then the other threads compute the `else` branch while the first wait. There's a reconvergence point *after* the if/else statement. Why then does the first example freeze, not having the loop split into two branches (a `true` branch for one thread and a waiting `false` branch for all the others in a warp)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to put the reconvergence point between the call to `while (s != threadIdx.x)` and `s++;`. It disrupts the program flow since the reconvergence point for a piece of code should be reachable by all threads at compile time. Below picture shows the flowchart of your first piece of code and possible and impossible points of reconvergence.

[image]

Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960487/2386951) about *recording the convergence point via `SSY` instruction*, I created below simple kernel resembling your first piece of code

```
__global__ void kernel_1() {
    __shared__ int s;
    if(threadIdx.x==0)
        s = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    while (s == threadIdx.x)
        s++; // serialized code
}
```

and compiled it for CC=3.5 with -O3. Below is the result of using `cuobjdum`binary tool for the output to observe the CUDA assembly. The result is:

[image]

I'm not an expert in reading CUDA assembly but I can see `while` loop condition checks in lines `0038` and `00a0`. At line `00a8`, it branches to `0x80` if it satisfies the `while` loop condition and executes the code block again. The *introduction* of the reconvergence point is at line `0058` introducing line `0xb8` as the reconvergence point which is after the loop condition check near the exit.

Overall, it is not clear what you're trying to achieve with this piece of code. Also in the second piece of code, the reconvergence point should be again after `while` loop code block (I don't mean between `while` and `if`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I realized that I, unfortunately, overlooked a semicolon at the end of the `while` statement and misinterpreted the example myself.
However, your explanation of (re)convergence points along with the referenced answer was very helpful for me and may be for other beginners. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it "hangs" is neither a HW deadlock nor branching, at least not directly. You produce an endless loop for one or multiple threads (as already suspected).

In your example, there isn't really a convergence point. Since you do not use any synchronization, there aren't any threads that actually wait. What happens here with the while-loop is pretty much a busy-wait. 
A kernel only finishes if all threads return. Since you have one (or multiple) endless loops (by accident maybe even none - this is unlikely however) the kernel will never finish.

You declared a shared variable s. This variable is known to all threads within a block.
With your while-statement you basically say (to each thread): increment s until it reaches the value of your (local) thread id. Since all threads are incrementing s in parallel, you introduce race conditions.
Example:

1. List item
2. Thread 5 is looping and checking for s to become 5
3. s is 4
4. Two threads increment s, it becomes 6
5. At the same time thread 5 only reached the end of its loop.
6. Now it reaches the next loop iteration and checks for s and it's not 5.
7. Thread 5 will never be able to finish since you check via == and the value of s already exceeded the value of the thread id.

Also your solution is quite confusing, because each thread executes the serialized code consecutively (which probably was the intention after all - even though that actually is strange):

1. Thread 0 will execute the serialized code
2. After that, thread 1 will execute the serialized code
3. and so on

Most examples show a program where each thread works on some code, then all threads are synchronized and only single thread executes some more code (maybe it needed the results of all threads).
So, your second example "works" because no thread is stuck in an endless loop, however I can't think of a reason why anyone would use such a code,
since it is confusing and, well, not parallel at all.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I realized that I, unfortunately, overlooked a semicolon at the end of the `while` statement and misinterpreted the example myself. So there is in fact an empty loop for threads with `threadIdx.x != s`, a convergency point after that loop and a thread waiting at the point for all the others without incrementing the `s` variable.